# rails nested resource undefined method for blog posts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to allow comments on a nested resource and I am getting an undefined method 'comment' for # in app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:7:in `create' when i select the create comment button. As I'm still new to ruby and rails, I followed the code in the getting started guide and I can't seem to figure out why the error.

Associations are:

```
has_many :comments
belongs_to :restaurant
```

In my routes

```
resources :restaurants do
    resources :comments
 end
```

In the comments controller

```
def create
    @restaurant = Restaurant.find(params[:restaurant_id])
    @comment = @restaurant.comments.create(params[:comment])
    redirect_to restaurant_path
end
```

In my restaurant show template

```
<%= form_for([@restaurant, @restaurant.comments.build]) do |f| %>
<h2>Add a comment</h2>
  <div>
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
  </div>
  <div>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: What is line 7 of `comments_controller`? I don't see any reference to a singular `comment` method anywhere.

Comment: Your route is not correct at the end of the create action, try with restaurant_path(@restaurant)

Comment: Thanks everyone. I still don't know what I missed but I deleted the code, started from scratch and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do the following on the first line in your create statement

```
raise params.to_yaml
```

You should see something like the following

```
utf8: ✓
authenticity_token: ...
comment: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
  commenter: Test Commenter
  body: Test Comment
commit: Create Comment
action: create
controller: comments
restaurant_id: '1'
```

The rest of your site should look something like the following

**comments_controller.rb**

```
def create
  @restaurant = Restaurant.find(params[:restaurant_id])
  @comment = @restaurant.comments.create(params[:comment])
  redirect_to restaurant_path(@restaurant)
end
```

**comments.rb**

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :comments
 belongs_to :restaurant
end
```

**restaurants.rb**

```
class Restaurant < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :content, :name, :title
 has_many :comments
end
```

You probably missed a step in guide.   Everything else looks to be alright.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I actually did take a look at railscasts 196 but it's not what I'm looking for or I'm unclear on how to edit it for my needs. The episode and the example above will create a nested form for adding a new restaurant profile and a new comment. I want to just allow comments on the existing restaurant profile. I followed the getting started guide code on how to do this. Unless the code is outdated, I can't see what's wrong.